# Ubuntu 12.04 always hang when progressing installation on IBM T23

Tags: installation

as in title. Specifications: P3 1.13 with RAM 1 GB. 
The last part I can access is "who are you", and after I press continue, the error message appeared, only "unsolveable problem", without specific message. Anyone has similar problem?

Comment: Did you [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM/) the ISO file?

Answer (score 0):

Besides [MD5 testing the `.iso` image file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM/) you downloaded (as [Mitch](https://askubuntu.com/users/59676/mitch) suggested), you should also [check the CD/DVD or live USB you made](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html), using the built-in facility.